# The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 8.2.1) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 8.2.0-alpha14

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, mobile

I'm encountering an issue with Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version in my project. Currently, I am using AGP 8.2.1, but its seems to be incompatible. The error message says that the latest supported version is AGP 8.2.0-alpha14.

```
[Error] Incompatible AGP Version: The project is using AGP 8.2.1, but the latest supported version is AGP 8.2.0-alpha14.
```

Tried syncing gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by downgrading gradle version in the libs.versions.toml file, in my case, I downgraded it to "8.1.0".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update Android Studio.

Comment: This could really use more information, like what the minimum compatible version is